# Vim quickfix/Latex-Suite go to error not working with Lualatex error output

Tags: vim, latex

I am using vim and Latex Suite for editing and compiling LaTeX documents. 
Quickfix is not able to resolve the error location when compiling with Lualatex (it works fine with the default compile rule).

One error output line in the quickfix window looks like this:

```
|11 error| Undefined control sequence. askdlfj\jsepackage {icomma}
```

There is no file specified so it is no surprise that vim can not go to the error. I am using the following compile rule in .vimrc:

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'lualatex -synctex=1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```

I've been trying to solve this for hours so any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself. "man luatex" (**not** lualatex) says:

```
--file-line-error
          Print error messages in the form file:line:error which is similar to the way many compilers format them.
```

So the correct compiler rule shoudl be

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'lualatex -synctex=1 -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```